# Vectorized version of Brent's algorithm (root-finding)

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on a Python version of the equation of state of seawater (http://www.teos-10.org/). The library depends on inverting equations like `p = f(t,d)` where you can directly calculate `f(t,d)` if you knew `t` and `d` but you typically have `t` and `p`. This is just a root-finding problem, and the library comes with options for using the Newton, bisection, or Brent methods. (For Brent method in particular, see the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method.)

However, the library finds the roots for single values of `t` and `p`. I want my version to be accessible to plotting and exploration of the equation of state, so I want to allow vector (numpy arrays) values of `t` and `p`. Vectorizing the Newton and bisection methods was fairly straightforward, but the Brent method has a lot of conditionals that I can't get my head around.

Any tips on how to vectorize this method? More importantly, would that vectorization actually be any faster than looping over the values in the `t` and `p` arrays?

Comment: I assume there is a reason why you aren't just using [`scipy.optimize.brent`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brent.html)?

Comment: The setup for the problem would be to find the root of `g(d; t,p)=0` for `d` in terms of `t` and `p`. I would like to be able to use arrays for `t` and `p` rather than scalars, which the standard scipy.optimize doesn't do, as far as I know.

Answer (score 5):

If you write a fully vectorized or array-oriented version of any iterative method, it can be come very inefficient.  For example, you might need a large number of iterations over a small part of your range while most of your range converges on a small number of iterations.

You could solve your equation over a coarse grid of `t` and `d` values with Brent's method.  Then use those solution values to get much closer initial guesses on the intermediate fine-grid values, for example with bicubic spline interpolation.  If those initial guesses are close enough for quadratic convergence, you won't need Brent's method on the intermediate values.  You could adaptively fill in the coarse grid using Brent's method and do the final fill-in to a finer grid with the vectorized Newton's method.

Comment: In this case, the library has a number of good approximations for the initial values, so I don't think it'll waste iterations trying to get uniform convergence. At the very least, I'd like to test out a vectorized version, just to see if it is slower than looping over the arrays.